# Wordpress Sql meta_value returns int instead of string

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have an issue retrieving a meta_value from wp_postmeta table, instead of a string I am getting just random number, maybe anyone knows how could I modify this query to make it work as I want. The third IF doesn't work, first 2 are fine.

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_title,meta.result,meta.odd,meta.pick
FROM `wp_posts`  
JOIN (
  SELECT post_id, sum( 
    if( meta_key = 'result', meta_value, 0 ) 
  ) AS result,  
  sum( 
    if( meta_key = 'odd', meta_value, 0 ) 
  ) AS odd, 
  if( meta_key = 'Pick', 'N/A', wp_postmeta.meta_value ) AS pick
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
GROUP BY post_id)as meta 
ON wp_posts.id = meta.post_id;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a reason why you are not using the get_post_meta() function which wordpress provides?

Answer (score 0):

instead of IF used this:
MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'pick' then wp_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as pick
and it worked.